# C++の出力イテレーターでのエラー

Tags: c++

下記コードを参考に出力イテレーターを書いてみたのですがエラーが出てうまくコンパイルが通りません。
`output_iteratorはclassではない`というような意味のエラーが出るのですが、なぜでしょうか?

参考にしたサイト:[江添亮のC++入門](https://ezoeryou.github.io/cpp-intro/#cb1149)

エラーメッセージ:

```
output_iterator.cpp:17:18: error: 'output_iterator' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
output_iterator& output_iterator::operator*() {
                 ^
output_iterator.cpp:4:8: note: 'output_iterator' declared here
struct output_iterator {
       ^
output_iterator.cpp:20:18: error: 'output_iterator' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
output_iterator& output_iterator::operator++(int) {
                 ^
output_iterator.cpp:4:8: note: 'output_iterator' declared here
struct output_iterator {
       ^
output_iterator.cpp:23:18: error: 'output_iterator' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
output_iterator& output_iterator::operator++() {
                 ^
output_iterator.cpp:4:8: note: 'output_iterator' declared here
struct output_iterator {
       ^
output_iterator.cpp:29:18: error: 'output_iterator' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
output_iterator& output_iterator::operator=(const T& x) {
                 ^
output_iterator.cpp:4:8: note: 'output_iterator' declared here
struct output_iterator {
       ^
4 errors generated.
```

参考にしたコード:

```
struct cout_iterator
{
// --- ボイラープレートコード
    // 出力イテレーターでは使わないのでvoidでいい
    using difference_type = void ;
    using value_type = void ;
    using reference = void ;
    using pointer = void ;
    // イテレーターカテゴリーは出力イテレーター
    using iterator_category = std::output_iterator_tag ;
    // 何もしない
    // 自分自身を返すだけ
    cout_iterator & operator *() { return *this ; }
    cout_iterator & operator ++() { return *this ; }
    cout_iterator & operator ++(int) { return *this ; }
// --- ボイラープレートコード

    // ここが肝心
    template < typename T >
    cout_iterator & operator =( T const & x )
    {
        std::cout << x ;
        return *this ;
    }
} ;


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5} ;
    cout_iterator out ;

    std::copy( std::begin(v), std::end(v), out ) ;
}
```

---

自分で書いてみたコード:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
template < typename T >
struct output_iterator {
    using difference_type = void;
    using value_type = void;
    using reference = void;
    using pointer = void;
    using iterator_category = std::output_iterator_tag;
    public:
        output_iterator& operator*();
        output_iterator& operator++();
        output_iterator& operator++(int);
        output_iterator& operator=(const T& x);
};

output_iterator& output_iterator::operator*() {
    return *this;
}
output_iterator& output_iterator::operator++(int) {
    return *this;
}
output_iterator& output_iterator::operator++() {
    return *this;
}

// assignment implementation
template < typename T >
output_iterator& output_iterator::operator=(const T& x) {
    std::cout << x;
    return *this;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    output_iterator out;
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), out);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template < typename T >
output_iterator<T>& output_iterator<T>::operator*() {
    return *this;
}
template < typename T >
output_iterator<T>& output_iterator<T>::operator++(int) {
    return *this;
}
template < typename T >
output_iterator<T>& output_iterator<T>::operator++() {
    return *this;
}

// assignment implementation
template < typename T >
output_iterator<T>& output_iterator<T>::operator=(const T& x) {
    std::cout << x;
    return *this;
}
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    output_iterator<int> out;
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), out);
}
```

こんな感じでテンプレート引数を追加してみてください。それでエラーは消えるはずです。

Comment: 宣言と定義を分けて書くときには1ヶ所しかtemplateをつかわなくても全てのメソッドに<T>をつける必要があるということでしょうか?

Comment: むしろテンプレートクラス宣言のなかで省略できることの方が特別だと思います。

Answer (score 2):

コメント欄に書くには長すぎるので回答欄で補足

> 宣言と定義を分けて書くときには

コンパイラから見て、提示例は「宣言と定義を分けて書いている」と解釈できません。最初の `template<typename T> struct output_iterator` はクラステンプレート、つまり「まだクラスぢゃない」わけです。

一方でクラス定義外（クラステンプレート定義外）に書かれた

```
output_iterator& output_iterator::operator*() {
    return *this;
}
```

は、ごく普通の関数定義です。クラステンプレートのメンバ関数定義とは読めません。

```
class myclass {
    int func(); // メンバ関数の関数宣言
};
int func() { ... } //  クラスに属さない関数の関数定義
```

と状況は同じです。

コンパイラにとっては `::` の左側 `output_iterator` は定義済み [クラス or 名前空間 or 列挙子] でなければなりません。クラステンプレートはまだクラスではないのでこの検索の対象になりません。エラーメッセージもその旨主張しています。

「クラステンプレートの」メンバ関数の関数定義と解釈してもらうには `output_iterator<T>` と書かなければならないので最初に `template <typename T>` が必要、となると @yudedako 氏のコードになります。

クラステンプレートが「まだクラスぢゃない」
関数テンプレートが「まだ関数ぢゃない」
のは理解を深めるうえでの重要ポイントです。
[関数テンプレートと関数のオーバーライドの違いが知りたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49418/)